# Strange "line" appears in GridView -- is it CSS or border or what?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview, internet-explorer-11

I see a "strange line" in my gridview.
Here is the screen-shot of the "strange line" at the right-edge of the cyan-blue selected gridview row:

[image]

I have used F12-developer tool and there is no reference to this "line" as shown in the image, below.
[image: F12 code related to the "strange line"]

What is also strange is when I change the browser VIEW/ZOOM to 300%, the "strange line" moves down to the last row visible in the screen-shot image.  Further, changing the VIEW/ZOOM to 200%, the "strange line" is no longer visible.

I have searched my code for underscores (2, 3 and 4 adjacent underscores) -- no finds.

I have searched for "border", not finding anything odd with those declarations.

I have searched my CSS for "-top" and "-bottom", nothing odd with those declarations.

I am seeking anyone's advice or solution.
Thanks...John

Comment: It probably has something to do with the active or hover css, and the last cell not being empty. Put the hidden input in another cell and see if that helps.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle, please?

Comment: @VDWWD Thank you for your comment which I shall mark as the ANSWER.  Thank you. You are VERY SMART.  I removed the last hidden column and that did the trick -- clean gridview , no "strange line".  Thank you

Comment: If you tell me what you do with that HiddenField, I will show you in my answer that you probably could do without it entirely. I assume it holds the ID of the item for that row?

Comment: @VDWWD -- You are correct.  That hidUID_CUSTOMER is the key/ID for that customer.  This page, was the first page of my ASP.NET coding career in building a web-application for an existing MS-Access app.  So I was on the beginning of learning curve of ASP.NET and did not know the "best way" to code.  I have it set up as a DataKeyName so the grid-row hidden field is not needed.  Please send in your answer so I can give you proper credit.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has something to do with the active or hover css, and the last cell not being empty. Put the hidden input in another cell and see if that helps.

You could also do without the HiddenField by using DataKeyNames or even better, strongly typed GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
```

Or strongly typed

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ItemType="Namespace.Class1.Class2">
```

With the last one you have access to the originating class and have type safety everywhere. I recommend the last one

https://www.sitepoint.com/asp-net-4-5-strongly-typed-data-controls-model-binding/

Comment: Thank you for your comment which I shall mark as the ANSWER. Thank you. You are VERY SMART. I removed the last hidden column and that did the trick -- clean gridview , no "strange line". Thank you – John D